# Modal not closed

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, state, use-state

In react.js, I want setShowModal to be false when the Backdrop component is clicked and the Backdrop component to be hidden, but setShowModal is not false and does not even show console.log ('a').

```
import { useState } from 'react';

import Backdrop from './Backdrop';
import Modal from './Modal';

function Todo(props) {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  function showModalHandler() {
    setShowModal(true);
  }

  function closeModalHandler() {
    setShowModal(false);
    console.log('a');
  }

  return (
    <div className='card'>
      <h2>{props.text}</h2>
      <div className='actions'>
        <button className='btn' onClick={showModalHandler}>
          Delete
        </button>
      </div>
      {showModal && <Modal />}
      {showModal && <Backdrop onClick={closeModalHandler} />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Todo;
```

Comment: you need pass the function closeModalHandler() as props and call it from Modal Component

Answer (score 1):

it seems that there was a problem with the binding of the `closeModalHandler` function. I've made some changes to your code and it is actually closing the modal and dropping the 'a' in the console.
Defining the functions as arrow functions use to help in these cases.
Hope it works to you.

```
import { useState } from 'react';


function Todo(props) {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(true);

  const showModalHandler = () => {
    setShowModal(true);
  }

  const closeModalHandler = () => {
    setShowModal(false);
    console.log('a');
  }

  return (
    <div className='card'>
      <h2>{props.text}</h2>
      <div className='actions'>
        <button className='btn' onClick={() => showModalHandler()}>
          Delete
        </button>
      </div>
      {showModal && <button> ShowModalIsActive</button>}
      {showModal && <button onClick={() => closeModalHandler()}>Button</button>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Todo;
```